# how to apt install only in one environment? or is there work around?

Tags: pip, package, conda, version, apt

I use conda becouse it allow me to experminent with diferent version, but some time there are package only in apt or pip. so if i use apt from inside the env will it effect others or modifie the base env.

let sey  install h5py for Python:
`conda activate -n test sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev sudo pip install h5py`

I am trying to understand. becouse if i try to install from inside the env and it moidifie the other env, it will be a problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

`apt` is an OS-level package manager for Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu). It installs packages globally, into the OS. It knows nothing about Python virtual environments.

If you want to install OS packages temporary, do experiments and then cleanup — use deeper virtualisation. Use virtual machines (qemu + Debian-in-Debian, VirtualBox + Ubuntu inside it) or containers (Docker, LXC, LXD, SystemD containers, whatever).